# Yandex map, open two maps or detach and reuse

Tags: window, maps, yandex-maps

I'm using yandex map on main page, 
Then I need to open wrap window ontop of main page with another map. how can I do it?
Or open new map or detach (with jquery) and reattach to new div.

Please advice!?

Thanks a lot
Alexei

Part of my js code:

```
ymaps.ready(init2);
    var myMap,
    myPlacemark;

    function init2(){     
        myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 7,
        });

    myMap.controls.add(
        new ymaps.control.ZoomControl()
    );

    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.64], { content: 'Moscow!', balloonContent: 'Capital of Russia' });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
    myMap.controls.add('map');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what a question? just call new ymaps.Map ("map2", { center: [55.76, 37.64], zoom: 7, });
with another block id

any problems?

P.S> i think it is a good practice to published answer to your own question if you found it

Comment: For some reason it didn't gave me. But I changed it to use only one map. I didn't find any solution. I'll try yours. Thanks

Comment: why not? You can duplicate state one map to another.